# Change button text color according to ImageSlider

Tags: android, arraylist

I want to change the color of button text as image change in ImageSlider. I used one library for making ImgeSlider.

Link for ImageSlider is:

https://github.com/denzcoskun/ImageSlideshow

My code is:

```
  //******************************** code for Image Slider**********************
    ImageSlider imageSlider = findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);
    ArrayList<SlideModel> imageList = new ArrayList<>();
    imageList.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.img1, ScaleTypes.CENTER_CROP));
    imageList.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.img2, ScaleTypes.CENTER_CROP));
    imageList.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.img3, ScaleTypes.CENTER_CROP));
    imageSlider.setImageList(imageList,ScaleTypes.CENTER_CROP);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can either use [setItemChangeListener](https://github.com/denzcoskun/ImageSlideshow/blob/8379c1e944932821f2ff70205b3786a7e46258c5/imageslider/src/main/java/com/denzcoskun/imageslider/ImageSlider.kt#L231) or call the listners below

```
imageSlider.setItemClickListener(object : ItemClickListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(position: Int) {
         button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")); 
                          or
         button.setTextColor(getApplication().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                          or
        button.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.red));
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

inside source of this lib, in `ImageSlider` class, you can find [`setOnItemChangeListener`](https://github.com/denzcoskun/ImageSlideshow/blob/8379c1e944932821f2ff70205b3786a7e46258c5/imageslider/src/main/java/com/denzcoskun/imageslider/ImageSlider.kt#L231) - use this method, register own interface and change text color inside called method